# I am not able to use webdriver-js-extender, inorder to access the mobile commands provided by protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, appium

My hook for webdriver-js-extender

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

        var extendedWebdriver = require('webdriver-js-extender').extend(webdriver);
```

on calling setNetworkConnection(5) using extendedWebdriver object it throows below mentioned error

```
extendedWebdriver.setNetworkConnection(5);
```

> Message:
>       Failed: Cannot read property 'defineCommand' of undefined   Stack:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineCommand' of undefined
>           at Extender.defineCommand (/Users/abhishek/abhishek-test-volunteeringMobileApp/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/lib/extender.ts:33:19)
>           at CommandDefinition.compile (/Users/abhishek/abhishek-test-volunteeringMobileApp/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/lib/command_definition.ts:13:16)
>           at Object.extend (/Users/abhishek/abhishek-test-volunteeringMobileApp/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/lib/index.ts:65:50)